# Git Cloning to Specific Folder?

Tags: git, github, sublimetext

Trying to learn how to clone this Soda Theme for Sublime Text 2 with this:

```
git clone https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/ "Theme - Soda"
```

as it says here: https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme

but I'm not sure where I type that in, or how to get it downloaded directly to my packages folder.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you have git and enter that `git clone https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/ <where you want to clone to>` command in terminal / console for your OS. The `<where you want to clone to>` is the path where you want the files to be checked out.

Comment: im on osx, and I  think I have git.. I installed the github app from mac.github.com and it said something about installing something in terminal but when i copy and paste this: "git clone https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/ /Users/joe/Library/Application Support/Packages" it says "-bash: git: command not found" so maybe git is not installed? How do I install it? and did I do that right?

Comment: I can get it to clone if I dont specify the directory where I want to clone it to but when I add "/Users/joe/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages" it says "Too many arguments." and shows me a list of git commands

Comment: @JoeBobby - If the path has space in it, enclose it in quotes - `"path/where/you/want/to/clone"`

Comment: in addition by adding 'git clone -b branch' option is possible to specify project branch which will be cloned